# How to edit a style of a div from a button with if?

Tags: html, css

I want the green ones to change to blue and green , and the Hi to change to Hello. Can somebody tell me in an easy html way how to edit the style and the written things with a button.

```js
function functionl {
  alert('success')
}
```

```css
.L1 {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 200% 0px 200% 0px;
  border-color: green;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 47%;
}

.L2 {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 0px 200% 0px 200%;
  border-color: green;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 47%;
}

.button1 {
  height=5%;
  font-size: 35;
  background-color: Red;
  color: blue;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

```html
<button class="L2">Hi</button><button class="L1">Hi</button><br>
<button class="L1">Hi</button><button class="L2">Hi</button>
<center><button class="button1" onclick="functionl()">Click me</button></center>
```

I want somebody to show me how to edit my code and how to edit any style from a button

Comment: Better duplicate: [How to change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/195951/5223757)

Comment: I'm aware of js but the problem is that it doesn't seem to work:    I tried "document.getElementById('L1').style[background-color]=red" and it still doesn't want to work I even tried attaching it to a function

Comment: Your answers are in the second link I posted. You made a typo in your JavaScript, as the error says; after the `function1` there should be a `(` (and after that there should be a `)`).

Comment: can you write the way document.getElement.... should be written?

Comment: Thank you I'm trying it

Comment: The function worked but this still doesn't --> "document.getElementById('L1').style[background-color]=red"

Comment: You need to write `backgroundColor`, because JavaScript doesn't like `-`s. `style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: can you write me the full line because I can't get it

Comment: Do you mean like this --> "document.getElementById('L1').style[backgroundcolor]=red"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```js
function functionl() {
  for (let e of document.querySelectorAll('.L1, .L2')) {
    if (e.innerText == 'Hi') {
      e.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      e.innerText = 'Hello';
    } else {
      e.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      e.innerText = 'Hi';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.L1 {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 200% 0px 200% 0px;
  border-color: green;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 47%;
}

.L2 {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 0px 200% 0px 200%;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 47%;
}

.button1 {
  height=5%;
  font-size: 35;
  background-color: Red;
  color: blue;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class="L2">Hello</button><button class="L1">Hi</button><br>
  <button class="L1">Hi</button><button class="L2">Hello</button>
  <center><button class="button1" onclick="functionl()">Click me</button></center>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm just going to tidy up your code a bit, if that's OK. It's very inefficient at the moment.

Comment: Go for it, I didn't have my coffee yet ;p

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Thank you.

Comment: @Miroslav Thank you

Comment: @Miroslav That OK? Still doesn't support IE11, but I don't think that's much of an issue.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Yes, that's okay. IE11 doesn't even want to support IE11 so no harm no foul :)

Comment: @Miroslav That's true. The ES6-only features of its New New New `about:tabs` page are amusing.